# How to skip providing default arguments in a Python method call that has a long list of named args that have defaults?

Tags: python, parameter-passing, keyword-argument

I'm calling this method from the Python [boto2 library](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/emr.html#boto.emr.step.StreamingStep):

```
boto.emr.step.StreamingStep(name, mapper, reducer=None, combiner=None, action_on_failure='TERMINATE_JOB_FLOW', cache_files=None, cache_archives=None, step_args=None, input=None, output=None, jar='/home/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming.jar')
```

I know that arguments after `mapper` have default values so I don't have to specify their values. But what if I want to pass a value for just *one* argument at the very end?  For example, I want to provide values for the `name`, `mapper`, and `combiner` parameters, and just use the default value for `reducer`.

Should I do this:

```
boto.emr.step.StreamingStep('a name', 'mapper name', None, 'combiner name')
```

Or should I expressly pass all arguments before it?

If there are 100 arguments, and I just want to pass a value for the very last argument, then I have to pass many default values to it. Is there a easier way to do this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two ways to do it. The first, most straightforward, is to pass a named argument:

```
boto.emr.step.StreamingStep(name='a name', mapper='mapper name', combiner='combiner name')
```

(Note, because `name` and `mapper` were in order, specifying the argument name wasn't required)

---

Additionally, you can pass a dictionary with `**` [argument unpacking](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
kwargs = {'name': 'a name', 'mapper': 'mapper name', 'combiner': 'combiner name'}
boto.emr.step.StreamingStep(**kwargs)
```

Comment: but you didn't use kwargs?

Answer (score 5):

Just pass the arguments you want by keyword: `boto.emr.step.StreamingStep(name='a name', mapper='a mapper', combiner='a combiner')`

Answer (score 1):

1. Do not use positional arguments,instead use keyword arguments.
2. If it is mandatory to use positional arguments,use *args list, populate it with default values using a loop or something ,and set last argument, then pass it to the method.