# Python: call function with default arguments that come before positional arguments

Tags: python, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

For example, I'd like to do something like: greet(,'hola'), where greet is:

```
def greet(person='stranger', greeting='hello')
```

This would help greatly for testing while writing code

Comment: try `greet(greeting="hola")`. Read more at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to skip argument in python when call method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21694536/how-to-skip-argument-in-python-when-call-method)

Answer (score 4):

Upon calling a function you can use the variable names to make it even more clear what variable will assume which value. At the same time, if defaults are provided in the function definition, skipping variables when calling the function does not raise any errors. So, in short you can just do this:

```
def greet(person='stranger', greeting='hello')
    print('{} {}'.format(greeting, person))
    return

greet(greeting='hola')  # same as greet(person='stranger', greeting='hola')
# returns 'hola stranger'
```

Note that, as I said above this would not work if for example your function definition was like this:

```
def greet(person, greeting)
    print('{} {}'.format(greeting, person))
    return
```

Since in this case, Python would complain saying that it does not know what to do with `person`; no default is supplied..

*And by the way, the problem you are describing is most likely the very reason defaults are used in the first place*

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the other parameters, and only knowing that the parameter you want to change is in second position you could use the `inspect` module to get function signature & associated default values.

Then make a copy of the default values list and change the one at the index you want:

```
import inspect

def greet(person='stranger', greeting='hello'):
    print(person,greeting)


argspec = inspect.getargspec(greet)

defaults = list(argspec.defaults)
defaults[1] = "hola"  # change second default parameter

greet(**dict(zip(argspec.args,defaults)))
```

Assuming that *all* parameters have default values (else it shifts the lists an that fails) that prints:

```
stranger hola
```